# read_fwf, skipping rows including footer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a fixed-width formatted file that looks like [image: this]

I want to skip the first 5 rows and the last row.

```
data = pd.read_fwf(path, skiprows=5, skipfooter=1, header=None)
```

It seems to read the first few columns as the first column. The first column I get is the one ending in U, possibly because of the footer in the text file, even though I have `skipfooter=1`. I should be getting ten columns, but I am only getting 5.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The following worked:

```
data = pd.read_fwf(bioassay, skipfooter=1, skiprows=5,header=None, usecols=[0], names=['All'])
data = data.All.str.split(expand=True)
```